# Force facebook api version

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to upgrade an app to use v2.x across all requests before April 2015 (I thought this was an option in the past).

The problem is, Facebook is saying ~81% of requests are 2.x, though I can't seem to locate the 19% of version unscoped requests which may be still falling back to 1.x.

Is there a way to force this change earlier, so testing can be made on an app?

Edit:
We're actually using OmniAuth, with the following:

> ```
> client_options: {
>   site: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2',
>   authorize_url: "https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth"
> }
> ```

Along with Koala:

> Koala.config.api_version = "v2.2"

Though it seems this hasn't correctly applied across the board and some requests are still being made with 1.x..

Comment: You shoud say what technology are you using. I asume is Ruby because you are using Koala too, but people won't find your question if you don't specify it!

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

With the JavaScript SDK, just use a newer version string in [FB.init](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/):

```
FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    status     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.0'
});
```

...or use the version tag in every call, as you can see in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

There is also an upgrading guide that may help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading